# Flutter: Error "The 'Pods-Runner' target has frameworks with conflicting names: appinvokesdk.xcframework."While installing app in IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I am trying to install my app in debug mode into IOS Simulator i got Following error:

```
-> Installing webview_flutter_wkwebview (0.0.1)
      - Running pre install hooks
    [!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has frameworks with conflicting names: appinvokesdk.xcframework.
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:67:in `verify_no_duplicate_names'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in verify_no_duplicate_framework_and_library_names'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:48:in `each_key'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:48:in `block in verify_no_duplicate_framework_and_library_names'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:47:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:47:in `verify_no_duplicate_framework_and_library_names'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:37:in `validate!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:597:in `validate_targets'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:163:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

I have try Some online solution like Clearing Cache file, deleting POD File and again install POD File but still cant find Solution for this error.

Comment: This link may help you: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76602

Comment: I tried this Solution but still i got the same error

Comment: Try to rename the `ios` folder under root (rename to have a backup if you need to revert it) and then run `flutter create . ` again, it will create a new `ios` folder. then run `flutter pub get` and `flutter run ... ` the ios version and see if that works

Comment: have you find any solution @MehulTandel?